# Vue - webpack vue-loader configuration

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, vue-loader

I keep getting error whenever I want to build a file. What is a reason of it? 
It seems that .vue file is not recognizable by webpack, but webpack configuration file looks properly.
webpack error

```
bundle-app.js   189 kB       1  [emitted]  app
    + 12 hidden modules

ERROR in Unexpected token >
 @ ./app/application.js 7:11-31
```

webpack.config.js

```
var path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  context: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
  entry: {
    app: './app/application.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle-[name].js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        include: /src/,
        query: {
          presets: ["es2015"]
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue',
      },
    ]
  },
  vue: {
    loaders: {
      js: 'babel'
    }
  }
}
```

package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "~2.2.1",
    "babel-core": "~6.23.1",
    "babel-loader": "~6.3.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "~6.22.0",
    "sass-loader": "~6.0.0",
    "node-sass": "~4.5.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "~2.0.0-rc.3",
    "vue-template-compiler": "~2.2.4",
    "css-loader": "~0.27.3",
    "vue-loader": "~11.1.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "~2.2.4"
  }
}
```

app/application.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './app.vue'

new Vue({
  el: 'body',
  component: { App }
})
```

app/app.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
  </div>
</template>

<script>

    export default {
      data () {
        return {
          msg: 'Hello from vue-loader!'
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Try to move es2015 preset to separated `.babelrc` file.It should looks something like this `{
  "presets": ["es2015"],
  "comments": false
}`
For more info check here https://github.com/bedakb/vuewp/blob/master/.babelrc
Also consider to NOT mount vue app to body tag,

Comment: @BelminBedak I've done it, but error's still occurring

Comment: Ah, since you are using webpack 2 you can't now omit the `-loader` keyword.Try change this `loader: 'vue'` to this `loader: 'vue-loader'`

Comment: Aren't you missing a close `</script>` after the export default {} ...?

Comment: @BelminBedak Still doesn't work.

Comment: @redconservertory Mea culpa, script tag is closed but of course I haven't copy entire script. Sorry :)

Comment: Found typo here `component: { App }` is should be components - plural.

Comment: @BelminBedak I am thankful for your help. The cause of whole mess was extremely silly. I've updated NPM and Node and everything works fine now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are some extra configs that you need to do, to loader work properly.

I strongly recommend you using the `vue-cli` for setup all working okay.

```
npm install -g vue-cli
vue init webpack-simple hello
cd hello
npm install
npm run dev
```

Basically, at your `webpack.config.js`, you forgot/made errors in:

1- Loader name should be `loader: 'vue-loader'` instead of `loader: 'vue'`.

2- Create an key called `resolve`, with the content:

```
alias: {
  vue$: 'vue/dist/vue.common.js',
}
```

3- And this key `vue: ...loader: babel`, isn't necessary.

Comment: I have multiple entry points in my webpack config file that I've been already working. I haven't wanted create a bigger mess with creating new project via vue-cli. However, in future I will init my vue projects that way. Obrigado :)

Comment: Wow! Does it work in that way? Strange. Anyway, I'm little worried too for using this tools that create everything, but in the case of vue-cli, it's very simple and tiny. Try creating in a demo folder, and see the webpack.config.

Comment: Yours is definitely the way to go. However, if you come from the Vue+Webpack tutorial and just want to add `vue-loader` to the equation, it's enough to just add the following to your webpack config: 
    `module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue-loader',
            },
        ]
    }`
I really don't know why the Vue documentation is so obscure at this point and forces you to use `vue-cli` when NPM-installing the modules and adding some lines to the webpack config suffices easily.

Answer (score 1):

In projects that use vue, individuals do not recommend configuring webpack and vue-loader separately. You can directly use vue official scaffolding, vue-cli. Do not have to consider these configurations, automatically configured.[vue-cli](https://vuejs.org/2015/12/28/vue-cli/)

If you just started learning Vue, here's an entry-level demo. Although it is only a small application, but it covers a lot of knowledge points (vue2.0 + vue-cli + vue-router + vuex + axios + mysql + express + pm2 + webpack), including front-end, back-end, database and other sites Some of the necessary elements, for me, learning great significance, would like to encourage each other!

[Vue Demo](https://github.com/alloyteamzy/vue2_blog/)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using vue-cli with ESLint?
If you do, you need a comma after every element event in the last and the semicolon.

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './app.vue';

new Vue({
  el: 'body',
  components: { App },
});
```